# finding nearest occurrence of timestamp in a column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe in R which is similar to this :

```
time                value
13-07-2019 02:34:28 9.07
13-07-2019 02:34:57 8.87
13-07-2019 02:35:27 9.34
13-07-2019 02:46:08 X
13-07-2019 02:46:38 4.5
13-07-2019 02:47:08 6.66
13-07-2019 02:47:37 8.7
13-07-2019 02:48:08 4.7
13-07-2019 02:48:39 X
13-07-2019 02:49:08 7.8
13-07-2019 02:49:39 9.8
13-07-2019 02:50:38 X
13-07-2019 02:51:08 2.34
13-07-2019 02:51:39 5.67
13-07-2019 02:52:08 X
13-07-2019 02:52:38 8.766
13-07-2019 02:53:08 5.456
13-07-2019 02:53:38 X
13-07-2019 02:54:08 6.544
13-07-2019 02:54:39 9.877
13-07-2019 02:55:08 X
```

What I want is to find out the nearest time when I have x. For example:

```
13-07-2019 02:35:27 9.34
13-07-2019 02:46:08 X
13-07-2019 02:46:38 4.5
```

Here nearest time is for X is `13-07-2019 02:46:38`

```
13-07-2019 02:53:08 5.456
13-07-2019 02:53:38 X
13-07-2019 02:54:08 6.544
```

Here it is `13-07-2019 02:53:08`

I need to consider only the time within 30 seconds. If it is exceeding 30 sec, I will assume that the time is previous 30 sec

```
13-07-2019 01:53:08 5.456
13-07-2019 02:53:38 X
13-07-2019 04:54:08 6.544
```

Here I need to limit the time to : `13-07-2019 02:53:08` which is the lower 30 second because it difference exceeds 30sec.

Finally I need to get a dataframe with n number of values where n is the number of times I have `x` in my dataframe value column

Comment: what's the desirable output ?

Comment: a dataframe with n number of values where n is the number of times I have x in my dataframe value column

Comment: and the time stamp value ?

Comment: Yes...Only timestamps are required

Comment: In your last example the difference is 30 minutes, not seconds.

Comment: @Alexis, thnks it is corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `data.table`,
here's one option assuming you have one
(named `dt` here)
and your times are strings
(if already `POSIXct`, skip the first line):

```
dt[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")]

max_difftime <- as.difftime(30L, units = "mins")
lambda <- function(rolled_time, x_time) {
    invalid <- abs(rolled_time - x_time) > max_difftime
    if (any(invalid)) {
        rolled_time[invalid] <- x_time[invalid] - max_difftime
    }
    rolled_time
}

dt[value != "X"
   ][dt[value == "X"],
     .(x_time = i.time, time = lambda(x.time, i.time)),
     on = "time",
     roll = "nearest"]
                x_time                time
1: 2019-07-13 02:46:08 2019-07-13 02:46:38
2: 2019-07-13 02:48:39 2019-07-13 02:49:08
3: 2019-07-13 02:50:38 2019-07-13 02:51:08
4: 2019-07-13 02:52:08 2019-07-13 02:51:39
5: 2019-07-13 02:53:38 2019-07-13 02:53:08
6: 2019-07-13 03:24:40 2019-07-13 02:54:40
```

I modified your sample data a bit so that the last row would have `03:24:40`.

The code performs a rolling join between the rows where `value` is `X` and the rest of the rows,
looking for the nearest `time`.
The `lambda` function compares the nearest time found
(exposed as `x.time` by `data.table`)
with the time where `X` is found
(exposed as `i.time` by `data.table`),
and adjusts values where the time difference is greater than 30 minutes.
I added the `x_time` column just to show the comparison,
you can remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: How can I superimpose to original dt? replacing old times for X with newly identified ones

Comment: @VictorJohnzon just save the result of the join and modify the original `dt` with it, something like `dt[value == "X", time := join_result$time]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just counting the number of X without non-NA values within +-30 seconds, you can do

1) Using non-equi join:

```
DT[!is.na(value)][
    DT[is.na(value), .(now=time, start=time-30, end=time+30)], 
    on=.(time>=start, time<=end), .(time=now, .N>0), by=.EACHI][, 
        sum(V2)]
```

2) Using `between`:

```
start <- DT2[!is.na(value), time-30]
end <- DT2[!is.na(value), time+30]
DT2[is.na(value), sum(sapply(time, function(x) !any(between(x, start, end))))]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("time,value
13-07-2019 02:34:28,9.07
13-07-2019 02:34:57,8.87
13-07-2019 02:35:27,9.34
13-07-2019 02:46:08,NA
13-07-2019 02:46:38,4.5
13-07-2019 02:47:08,6.66
13-07-2019 02:47:37,8.7
13-07-2019 02:48:08,4.7
13-07-2019 02:48:39,NA
13-07-2019 02:49:08,7.8
13-07-2019 02:49:39,9.8
13-07-2019 02:50:38,NA
13-07-2019 02:51:08,2.34
13-07-2019 02:51:39,5.67
13-07-2019 02:52:08,NA
13-07-2019 02:52:38,8.766
13-07-2019 02:53:08,5.456
13-07-2019 02:53:38,NA
13-07-2019 02:54:08,6.544
13-07-2019 02:54:39,9.877
13-07-2019 02:55:08,NA
14-07-2019 01:53:08,5.456
14-07-2019 02:53:38,NA
14-07-2019 04:54:08,6.544")
DT[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")]
DT2 <- copy(DT)
```